# Filling options values dynamically to dynamically added dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding dropdowns dynamically by code it is rendered in browser like

```
   <select id="contact-type1"></select> 
   <select id="contact-type2"></select>
   ...
```

Now I am trying the below code for dynamically selecting nth number of dropdown in order to fill option values in them.

```
          function fillContactTypes()
        {
          var types = ["Phone","Whatapp","Facebook","Web","Fax"];     
          var select = document.getElementById('contact-type[*n]');
          for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) 
          {
               var option = document.createElement('option');
               option.innerHTML = types[i];
               option.value = types[i];
               select.appendChild(option);
           }
        }
```

Please help me in the line "var select = document.getElementById('contact-type[*n]');
".

Comment: `fillContactTypes()` has no parameter, how will you determine what `*n` is suppose to be? In your current code you might as well hardcode `contact-type1` or `2`. Is it a feasible solution to do this dynamic? How many contact types will you have? If you only have a few, why not be explicit `<select id="contact-type-social-media"></select>` and use `function fillSocialMediaContactTypes()` and `document.getElementById('contact-type-social-media')` etc... Why do they need to be dynamic?

Comment: instead of ID, add a class to selects, get elements by class and iterate through them.

Comment: Also your `types` are hardcoded. How will you change them for each dropdown? If your intend is to fill the same options into each dropdown then use a data attribute such as `data-id="contact"` and `document.querySelectorAll('[data-id=contact]` then iterate through each dropdown in the resultset and apply your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added common class to all dropdowns and using jquery you can dynamically bind all dropdown as shown below.

```js
var types = ["Phone","Whatapp","Facebook","Web","Fax"];     
$(document).ready(function(){
  fillContactTypes()
});
function fillContactTypes(){
 var myselect = $('<select>');
     $.each(types, function(index, key) {
      myselect.append( $('<option></option>').val(key).html(key) );
       });
      $('.contact-type').append(myselect.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>

<select  id="contact-type1" class="contact-type">

</select>
<select  id="contact-type2" class="contact-type">

</select>
<select  id="contact-type3" class="contact-type">

</select>
<select  id="contact-type4" class="contact-type">

</select>
```